# Encountering Error while using loc. function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I am trying to choose the particular rows for plotting in python and for slicing the rows, I am using the slicing function. I am encountering the following error:-

```
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'
```

Given below is my code:

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
#plt.style.use('seaborn')

load_var=pd.read_excel(r'path\filename.xlsx')
col_var=load_var.loc[0:5732,['col1','col2','col3']]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
# make a plot

ax.plot(s[0:5732]['col1'],s[0:5732]['col1'],color='r')
plt.show()
```

I have visited their website for help, but it didn't help.

Would appreciated if you, Please suggest the changes in the code itself.
Thank you.

Comment: Does `load_var` indeed have all three columns col1, col2, col3 _and_ 5733 rows?

Comment: Yes, it's there  in the columns.

Comment: Hey, DYZ it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use iloc, so:

```
ax.plot(s.iloc[0:5732]['col1'], s.iloc[0:5732]['col1'],color='r')
```

Comment: Didn't helped out!